# Ошибка при запуске в debug режиме nodejs приложения (intellij idea 14)

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, отладка

Запускаю приложение в debug'e, стартует, но выдает ошибку:

```
Cannot stop on breakpoint due to internal error: org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor$1
```

Нашел информацию в сети, и действительно webstorm последней версии работает корректно, но все же мне необходимо запустить его в idea..